# Ordering ArrayList of points to follow closest point LibGDX Java

Tags: java, arraylist, libgdx

I have an ArrayList of Vector2 (Vector2 is an object that contains an x and y coordinate) that contains a bunch of vertices that make a shape when drawn. However, the way they were put into the ArrayList are out of order. For example, the starting Vector2 point is index 0 but the closest next point is of index 4. My goal is to have another ArrayList of Vector2 that orders the Vector2's in a way so that the starting point is index 0, the next closest point is index 1, next is index 2, etc. Here is an image of what is happening.

The image shows what is happening but the green arrows show what I want to happen. The green point is the starting point.
[image]

So what I need is once the new ArrayList is created and ordered, it should look like this:

[image]

So here is the code in which I thought would do it:

```
public Array<Vector2> orderedVertices;
private void cleanVertices(Array<Vector2> originalVertices){

    //This will be the Array containing ordered vertices
    orderedVertices = new Array<Vector2>();

    //Copy vertices of unsorted Array in a new Array
    Array<Vector2> verticesOfImage = originalVertices;


    //Add a random vertice to begin with (starting point)
    orderedVertices.add(verticesOfImage.get(1));

    //For breaking loop
    int originalArraySize = originalVertices.size;

    for(int i = 0; i < orderedVertices.size; i++){
        //Index to be compared, meaning to find closest vertice around this vertice
        int indexOfCompare = i;
        //Get a distance for reference                                                     //Random point to check
        double currentDistance = MathFactory.distance(orderedVertices.get(indexOfCompare), verticesOfImage.get(0));

        //If we found a closest vertice, add to ordered pair and remove from original
        // So we don't go backwards
        if(getClosest(verticesOfImage, indexOfCompare, currentDistance) != -1){
            orderedVertices.add(verticesOfImage.removeIndex(getClosest(verticesOfImage, indexOfCompare, currentDistance)));
        }
        //If not, then the original 'currentDistance' check was the closest vertice
        else
            orderedVertices.add(verticesOfImage.removeIndex(0));

        //Stop checks, ordered pair fully populated
        if(orderedVertices.size == originalArraySize)
            break;

    }

}

public int getClosest(Array<Vector2> vertices, int checkedIndex, double currentDistance){
    //This is used to find the closest vertice, defaulted to -1 for condition statements
    int correctIndex = -1;

    for(int k = 0; k < vertices.size; k++){
        //Make sure to not check same Vector2
        if(vertices.get(k).x == orderedVertices.get(checkedIndex).x && vertices.get(k).y == orderedVertices.get(checkedIndex).y){
            continue;
        }
        if(MathFactory.distance(orderedVertices.get(checkedIndex), vertices.get(k)) < currentDistance){
            correctIndex = k;
            currentDistance = MathFactory.distance(orderedVertices.get(checkedIndex), vertices.get(k));

        }

    }
    return correctIndex;
}
```

This code comes very close to working, here is an image explaining what is going wrong.

[image]

I understand the one that isn't working doesn't look as smooth, but the only real problem is the fact that the lines freak out at the end and go through the body. I can't seem to figure out why this is happening or how to fix it. Any help at all with this is hugely appreciated! Thank you!

Comment: I didn't look at your algorithm in detail, but the way you describe it, the result is pretty much what you would expect. Some points will be "skipped" when nearest ones are found. You will need a different method.

Comment: You should consider that this algorithm will not always work. In the first image, **the rightmost point would likely be skipped**. There may be ambiguities or points that are skipped. How should they be treated? In the resulting image, one could imagine that this happened for the small white part at the hand of the figure, causing the longest diagonal line to appear.  Beyond that, it's hard to spot potential bugs by just looking at the code (e.g. if there is a bug regarding the "random first point" that you are comparing with, etc). (EDIT: Yeah, a few seconds too slow...)

Comment: The task is equivalent to the Travelling Salesman Problem, which is NP-hard. There are various approximations though, which should be sufficient.